# Blazor in Electron: Window not showing

Tags: electron, blazor

Trying to run a Blazor Server App inside an Electron shell.
On latest macOS with .NET 6 runtime & latest ElectronNET.CLI.

Tried a few things as per the docs .. here is my Program.cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using BlazorInElectron.Data;
using ElectronNET.API;
using ElectronNET.API.Entities;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddElectron();

builder.WebHost.UseElectron(args);
var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

if (HybridSupport.IsElectronActive)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var browserWindow = await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync(
            new BrowserWindowOptions
            {
                Title = "BlazorInElectron",
                Width = 1152,
                Height = 864,
                Show = true
            });
        browserWindow.OnReadyToShow += () => browserWindow.Show();
        browserWindow.OnClosed += () =>
        {
            Electron.App.Quit();
        };
    });
}

app.Run();
```

App runs fine in browser with *dotnet run*, but *electronize start* does not work. Looks like the app bootstraps, but Electron window does not show. What am I missing?

[image]